# Using jQuery to search through element attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a filter on screen, by just hiding what doesn't meet the requirements.

This what I've come up with so far. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

jQuery :

```
jQuery('#searchBox').on('keyup change', function() {
    var search = $('#searchBox').val();
    

    //for each h4       
    $('h4').each(function(){
     var h4id = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(h4id).contains(search))
            $(this).show();
         else
            $(this).hide
    });
```

HTML :

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="searchBox"/>

<h4 id="Adminstrator">Administrator</h4> 
<h4 id="John,Smith">John Smith</h4> 
<h4 id="Jane,Smith">Jane Smith</h4>
```

(I'm using jQuery 1.9.1)
(So, if I start typing Smith, "Administrator" h4 should disappear.

Comment: First off, you're putting a string inside a jQuery object. That will virtually never work well.

Comment: Take a look at this plugin. http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/

Comment: how could `Administrator` appear when you type `Smith`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.contains will not give you the text content of the selector. It will only search for elements inside the selector.

Try this approach .. This can be lot more optimized

```
jQuery('#searchBox').on('keyup change', function () {
    var search = $('#searchBox').val().toLowerCase();

    $('h4').hide();
    $('h4').each(function () {
        var h4id = $(this).attr('id'),
            $text = $('#'+ h4id).text().toLowerCase();
        if($text.indexOf(search) > -1) 
            $(this).show();
    });

});
```

Make sure your **id's** are unique.

Next is your id's should not contain **,** in them

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eSgZc/)**

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this:-
Simple one, but case sensitive though</strike>

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raBGw/)

```
  jQuery('#searchBox').on('keyup change', function() {
         var search = $('#searchBox').val();
      $('h4').hide();
      $('h4[id*='+ search + ']').show();

    });
```

See if this helps. I won't use id for storing the string comparison since name can be same for multiple people and you might end up having multiple h4s with same id. SO i am using data-attribute and jquery data here.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GDFcd/)

```
 jQuery('#searchBox').on('keyup change', function() {
         var search = $('#searchBox').val();
      $('h4').hide().filter(function(_,oj){
       return $(oj).data('key').toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
     //if your are trying to match the text() then do  
     //return $(oj).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      }).show();
     });
```

Fixing your code would mean this. There is no `contains` function and couple of other typos.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dzea/)

```
jQuery('#searchBox').on('keyup change', function() {
    var search = $('#searchBox').val();
  //for each h4       
    $('h4').each(function(){
     var h4id = this.id;

        if (h4id.indexOf(search) > -1)
        //if your are trying to match the text() then do  
        //if ($('#'+h4id).text().indexOf(search) > -1)
            $(this).show();
         else
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex based solution

```
jQuery('#searchBox').on('keyup change', function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');

    //for each h4       
    $('h4').hide().filter(function(){
        return regex.test(this.id)
    }).show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T4UtH/)

Answer (score 0):

Just using jQuery attribute selector,see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/),just two line code will be enough.
Demo:

```
//for each h4       
var h4id = $(this).attr('id');
$("h4").hide().filter("[id*=" + h4id + "]").show();
```